# Automate updating outdated dependencies in CI/CD using `yarn outdated`

Tags: continuous-integration, yarnpkg, continuous-delivery

My team is developing a React component library which relies on MaterialUI components. The customer of our employer wants to automatically signal and/or upgrade outdated dependencies (specifically when the dependency on MaterialUI becomes outdated at least). We are using yarn as dependency manager.

I found yarn lists all the outdated dependencies (or a specific dependency if specified) through the `yarn outdated` command. One can then upgrade said dependencies using the `yarn upgrade` command to which the dependency to be updated is supplied as parameter. To do this using a single command, running `yarn upgrade-interactive` lists outdated dependencies which the user can then select to be updated.

I am wondering if there is/are way(s) to automate this process. I tried piping the results of `yarn outdated` to `yarn update` as well as `yarn version`, but `yarn upgrade` seems to ignore whatever input it receives and updates every package regardless and `yarn version` throws errors saying the version are not proper semvers.

I realise `yarn upgrade-interactive` makes this process easy and quick for developers, however the project is intended to become open-source over time and the customer prefers a centralised solution rather than relying on every individual contributor to track this themselves. As far as I am aware, `yarn upgrade-interactive` cannot be automated as it requires user input in order to select the package(s) to be updated.

Other solutions I found, such as Dependabot or packages like 'yarn-outdated-notifier', seem to only work with GitHub. The project is currently running on Azure DevOps and, when it goes public, will run on GitLab.

Is there any way we could do this in our CI/CD environment or with any (free) solutions? The customer prefers to have as few dependencies as possible.

Comment: You can't just pipe that output but you can pass all `outdated` packages to `update` using xargs once you've formatted the output correctly. There's an example in [this package](https://github.com/masawada/yarn-outdated-formatter) to do just that: `yarn outdated --json | $(yarn bin)/format-yarn-outdated --format json | jq '.minor[],.patch[] | .[0]' | xargs -I{} yarn upgrade {}`

Comment: @jonrsharpe could you talk me through what happens in each pipe? I understand the first one outputs `yarn outdated` to `json` and that the second saves it to a .json-file in the yarn bin, but I'm not too sure what `jq '.minor[],.patch[] | .[0]'` and `xargs -I{} yarn upgrade {}` do..

Comment: No, the second uses an executable in the yarn binaries directory to process the JSON, otherwise you wouldn't be able to pipe it further. For the others see https://stedolan.github.io/jq/, https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html.

Comment: Thanks for the links, I think I understand what's happening now. I'm just having difficulty finding out how I would use jq in CI/CD?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm also quite unsure about some things. How does your command know which package is corresponding to the version? And also, is the JSON formatting necessary? As far as I can find `yarn outdated --json` outputs valid JSON..

Comment: It's not my command, I found it by researching your problem. You can look at exactly what that package does, it's open source, but of course the Yarn output is valid JSON - presumably it's rearranging it to a more usable form. Perhaps you could do the whole thing *just* with jq, and you could certainly do the whole thing in JS if you wrote your own.